# Baseline for Precision-Related Metrics

Tags: classification, precision-recall, loss-functions, metric, average-precision

When working with ROC-AUC as a metric for binary classification, one often considers a value of 0.5 as a baseline from a random classifier (i.e. a data-blind classifier that randomly classifies test instances with equal probability).

I have read that **average precision** (or more generally, mean average precision) may be a better metric when the **positive** class is of higher interest than the **negative** class. This claim deserves its own question, but aside from that, what is a reasonable random baseline for (baseline) average precision?

I am inclined to think that such random baseline should be **P/(P+N)** (i.e. fraction of positives of the total). How should I go about stablishing this baseline?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "baseline" in precision recall curve](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251175/what-is-baseline-in-precision-recall-curve)